# Telegram messenger colored box filled with the initials of the contacts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a chat website which is similar to Telegram(http://zhukov.github.io/webogram/#/im?p=u67212536_13900205441461158827) . You can see in the contacts section that the first letter of the contact name is taken and it is placed in a colored box. I am attaching the screenshot of it with this question. I have tried this code, but I am failing to implement it.
Here is the code which I have written. I am using bootstrap to make it happen. 
I know that I have to add the code to the li tag.[image]

```
    sortedarray = eliminateDuplicates(removedups);
    console.log(sortedarray);
    sortedarray.sort();
    sortedarray = sortedarray.filter(emptyElement);
    for(r=0;r<sortedarray.length;r++){
    var contact = $('#contact');
    var display = $('#display');
    var newcontact= $('<li><a href="#">' + sortedarray[r] + '</a></li>');
    contact.append(newcontact);
    }
```

You can see in the image below that the initials of the names are displayed in the colored circle.

Comment: too many undefined functions and variables for anyone here to help without seeing more code

Comment: I have the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have the solution for it.
        var contact = $('#contact');
        var display = $('#display');
        initial = sortedarray[r].slice(0,1)+" "+sortedarray[r].slice(1,2);
        var newcontact= $('<div><span class="peer_initials im_dialog_photo   user_bgcolor_8">'+initial+'</span><li><a> ' + sortedarray[r] + '</a></li>   </div>');
        contact.append(newcontact);
        }
        div.im_dialog_photo .peer_initials {
         line-height: 48px;
         font-size: 18px;
         }
      .im_dialog_photo {
  width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
        line-height: 48px;
         border-radius: 50%;
       overflow: hidden;
        }
.peer_initials {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.user_bgcolor_8 {
  background: #fba76f;
```